# How to initialize C struct members at creation in SWIG for Python?

Tags: python, c, struct, swig

Let's say we have a following struct in C:

```
typedef struct buffer
{
    uint8_t* const data;
    const size_t maxSize;
    size_t size;
} buffer_t;
```

How can I make a SWIG wrapper for this so that when buffer_t is created in Python it allocates given number of bytes to data pointer and sets maxSize accordingly?

**Details**

So basically the problem here is related to constant struct members. By default SWIG initializes structs with default values. This leads into problems:

```
StructWithConsts_t struct;
struct.constant = 5; // Error. This should've been set when creating the struct.
```

The accepted answer with constructors and destructors provide solution for this problem.

Comment: You should provide a minimal reproducing example.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the problem was implicitly clear. I'll add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat C structs as C++ classes in SWIG and extend them with creators and destroyers methods.

In your case your `.i` should have this

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t* const data;
    const size_t maxSize;
    size_t size;
} buffer_t;

%extend buffer_t {
    buffer_t(size_t size)
    {
        buffer_t* pBuffer = malloc(sizeof *pBuffer);
        pBuffer->data = malloc(size * sizeof (*pBuffer->data));
        pBuffer->maxSize = size;
        return pBuffer;
    }

    void ~buffer_t()
    {
        buffer_t *pBuffer = ($self);
        free(pBuffer->data);
        free(pBuffer);
        return;
    }
};
```

In python it will be used like this

```py
from yourmodule import buffer_t

buffer = buffer_t(10)
```

The garbage collector will take care of freeing the memory.

There are other ways of doing this but you don't have a reproducing example to test it out.

Comment: This is much cleaner interface! Thanks! This does not work though if the members are constant. To address that issue the const members needs to be cast into non-const for assignment. Looks filthy, but it's the only way.

Comment: @JuhoL You can initialize constants in a constructor but the syntax is different: `buffer_t(size_t size) : data(malloc(sizeof *pBuffer)) { ... }` for example.  Difficult to error check, though. Casting a constant to non-constant has risks if the constant memory is read-only.  You're invoking undefined behavior here.  Better to make the members of the struct non-const, and return a const structure when it is used.

Comment: Malloc allocations are guaranteed to be in heap, so no risk there, but you are right that in general casting consts to non-consts is extremely bad idea and it is strictly forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, but it is rather hackish due to pointer typecasts. I'm not convinced that this is the proper way to do this, but it works:

In the .i file I created a wrapper using %inline:

```
%inline %{
buffer_t* new_buffer(size_t size)
{
    buffer_t* pBuffer = (buffer_t*)malloc(sizeof(buffer_t));
    *(uint8_t**)&pBuffer->data = (uint8_t*)malloc(size * sizeof(uint8_t));
    *(size_t*)&pBuffer->maxSize = size;
    return (buffer_t*)pBuffer;
}

void free_buffer(buffer_t* pBuffer)
{
    free(pBuffer->data);
    free(pBuffer);
    return;
}
%}
```